# BxSlider Gets Stuck On Tab Change

Tags: jquery, bxslider

I testing BxSlider on website in tabs. BxSlider located in first Tab-1 and visible on page load and working fine. But as soon as i click on Tab-2 or Tab-3 and come back to Tab-1 where BxSlider located. BxSlider get stuck i cant see any errors in browser Console and i have to refresh page to get slider working again.
My code:

```
<div class="bxslider">
  <div><img src="/assets/images/coffee1.jpg"></div>
  <div><img src="/assets/images/coffee2.jpg"></div>
  <div><img src="/assets/images/coffee3.jpg"></div>
  <div><img src="/assets/images/coffee1.jpg"></div>
  <div><img src="/assets/images/coffee2.jpg"></div>
  <div><img src="/assets/images/coffee3.jpg"></div>
</div>

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  auto: true,
  autoControls: true,
  stopAutoOnClick: true,
  pager: true,
  slideWidth: 600
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Page Visibility API](https://scotch.io/tutorials/get-to-know-the-page-visibility-api#toc-usage-of-the-page-visibility-api)

The Page Visibility API allows us to register the [`visibilitychange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/visibilitychange) event. Upon losing visibility of the targeted or registered element the `visibilitychange` is triggered. One of the use cases mentioned is exactly the same as the OP.

> [*"Stop movement of a slider carousel when the page has lost focus."*](https://scotch.io/tutorials/get-to-know-the-page-visibility-api#toc-usage-of-the-page-visibility-api)

---

### Demo

**Details commented in demo.**

```js
/*
Store the instantiation of bxSlider object in a variable (var bx)
*/
var bx = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  auto: true,
  autoControls: true,
  stopAutoOnClick: true,
  pager: true,
  slideWidth: 600
});
// Declare hidden property
var hidden = "hidden";

// Define the event handler
function windowBlur() {
  // if hidden property is true...
  if (document[hidden]) {
    // Stop bxSlider
    bx.stopAuto();
    // Otherwise...
  } else {
    // Redraw and start bxSlider
    bx.redrawSlider();
    bx.startAuto();
  }
}
// Register the document to the event
document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', windowBlur);
```

```css
.bx-wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.15/jquery.bxslider.min.css" />
  <style></style>
</head>

<body>
  <main class="bxslider">
    <section>
      <img src='https://i.ibb.co/tmQZgJb/68eb2df1a189f88bb0cbd47a3e00c112.png'>
    </section>
    <section><img src="https://i.ibb.co/ZHvWsKb/o1z7p.jpg"> </section>
    <section><img src="https://i.ibb.co/5LPXSfn/Lenna-test-image.png"> </section>
  </main>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.15/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
  <script></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi still the same issues as soon as change tabs and come back slider gets stuck.

Comment: @DeividasKrupstas Sorry forgot to define `hidden` try it now.